# Yesod: how to send Redis results as JSON

Tags: json, haskell, io, redis, yesod

Apologies in advance for my Haskell inexperience.  I am writing a little wrapper for a Redis instance for a learning project.  So far Yesod has been an absolute wonder.  With very little Haskell experience I got browserId Auth working, and I'm inserting records into Redis successfully and quickly.

I'm stuck figuring out how to get the Redis responses converted into JSON and sent back.  Here is a working, un-scaffold, app that shows getting a static RepJson or a RepPlain with Redis info (App is called LRedis):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies,
             MultiParamTypeClasses, QuasiQuotes #-}

import Yesod
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Encoding
import Data.ByteString.UTF8
import Database.Redis
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L


data LRedis = LRedis

instance Yesod LRedis where

mkYesod "LRedis" [parseRoutes|
    / HomeR GET
    /learnJson LearnJsonR GET
    /redisWorks RedisWorksR GET
    |]

getHomeR :: Handler RepHtml
getHomeR = do
    defaultLayout[whamlet|
    <p>Hi this is a headless API thing.
    |]

getLearnJsonR :: Handler RepJson
getLearnJsonR = do
    jsonToRepJson $ object [("json", ("ftw"::Text))]

getRedisWorksR :: Handler RepPlain
getRedisWorksR = do
    conn <- liftIO $ connect defaultConnectInfo
    liftIO $ runRedis conn $ do
        result <- Database.Redis.get (fromString "hello")
        case result of
            Left e -> return $ RepPlain "Error"
            Right mAnswer -> do
                case mAnswer of
                    Nothing -> return $ RepPlain "Not found."
                    Just x -> return $ RepPlain (toContent x)

main :: IO()
main = do
    warpDebug 3000 $ LRedis
```

Again, that is all working.  It will return the string stored in "hello" in redis if you curl `/redisWorks`, or it will return JSON if you curl `/learnJson`, but I want to give the redis answer as JSON, not a plain string.  I thought I could just naively combine the two, like:

```
getRedisJsonR :: Handler RepJson
getRedisJsonR = do
    conn <- liftIO $ connect defaultConnectInfo
    liftIO $ runRedis conn $ do
        result <- Database.Redis.get (fromString "hello")
        case result of
            Left e -> jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ("error"::Text))]
            Right mAnswer -> do
                case mAnswer of
                    Nothing -> jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ("Nothing"::Text))]
                    Just x -> jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ((decodeUtf8 x)::Text))]
```

But after adding the route `/redisJson RedisJsonR GET` it fails with this compilation error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Redis a0'
            with actual type `GHandler sub0 master0 RepJson'
In the expression:
  jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ("error" :: Text))]
In a case alternative:
    Left e -> jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ("error" :: Text))]
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  case result of {
    Left e -> jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ("error" :: Text))]
    Right mAnswer
      -> do { case mAnswer of {
                Nothing -> ...
                Just x -> ... } } }
```

It seems like its telling me I need to do something different with the `result` in case of an error, but I don't know what that would be, or why it's necessary given the RepPlain version is working.

**Is there an example of getting the results from Redis into JSON within Yesod?

Is there just something simple I'm doing wrong with IO or something?**

Convenient link to Hedis docs: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis   Thank you for helping me with this.  Sorry again if it turns out to be super simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getRedisJsonR :: Handler RepJson
getRedisJsonR = do
    conn <- liftIO $ connect defaultConnectInfo
    res <- liftIO $ runRedis conn $ do
        result <- Database.Redis.get (fromString "hello")
        case result of
            Left e -> return $ jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ("error"::Text))]
            Right mAnswer -> do
                case mAnswer of
                    Nothing -> return $ jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ("Nothing"::Text))]
                    Just x -> return $ jsonToRepJson $ object [("response", ((decodeUtf8 x)::Text))]
    res
```

I actually don't trust myself to explain why this works and your original code doesn't -- I've been programming in Haskell on a daily basis for just under three months, so I have a developing gut sense for what will work but I'm really not there yet on the theory side, especially when it comes to stacked monads, which I think is what we're dealing with here (either Redis is on top of Handler or vice versa, and liftIO is facilitating the stacking).

Hopefully someone else can weigh in -- seems like a great concrete example to illustrate some monad concepts.